# Treating numerical variables as text

Tags: c, command-line, cs50

I was not sure how to title this question, so I'll go straight to the code for you to see what I mean. Really new into this, so bear with me!

I have this code:

```
1   #include <cs50.h>
2   #include <stdio.h>
3   #include <string.h>
4
5   int main(int argc, string argv[])
6   {
7 
8   if (argc!=2)
9   {
10     printf("error!! Usage: ./caesar k\n");
11     return 1;
12   }
13
14   printf("Plaintext: ");
15   string text=get_string();
16 
17   char k=argv[1][0];
18   int n=strlen(text);
19 
20 
21   for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
22   {
23     if(text[i]>='a' && text[i]<='z')
24     {
25         printf("Cyphertext: %c\n", text[i]+k);
26     }
27   }
28   }
```

**What's its purpose?**
Well, given a text, it adds `k` to every character. Which means that, for `abc`, and `k=1`, the output would be `bcd`; for `abc` and `k=3`, output would be `def`.

Now, it is imperative that `k` is given as a command line argument.

**What do I want to do?**
Just take `k` (which is a number), add it to every character of the input `string text`, and voilà.
Since every letter is a number in ASCII, adding a number can change the character, so... it should work. [I am still trying to figure out how ASCII works, and when do `char` show up like charcters and not numbers... but anyway].

**What is going on?**
**First**, I am having trouble declaring `k` as an `int` or `char`. In line 17, -and although `k` is a number(!)- the IDE forces me to declare a string or char*: if I declare `k` as `int` I receive an error; if I declare `char` I receive an error too, unless I declare it not only as `k=argv[1]` but as `k=argv[1][0]`, as shown in the code above.

**Second**, executing the code above, this is the *input*/output (the name of the program is caesar):

```
$./caesar
error!! Usage: ./caesar k

$./caesar 1
Plaintext: a
Cyphertext: (nothing...)
```

**Third**, given the error above, I changed the code in line 25 from this:

```
printf("Cyphertext: %c\n", text[i]+k);
```

to this:

```
printf("Cyphertext: %s\n", text[i]+k);
```

which returned this error message:

```
caesar.c:25:38: error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has 
type 'int' [-Werror,-Wformat]
        printf("Cyphertext: %s", text[i]+k);
                            ~~   ^~~~~~~~~
                            %d`
```

error message I do not understand, given that neither `text` nor `k` are `int`.

Anyway, changing `%c` to `%s` did not work, so I tried with `%i` instead:

```
printf("Cyphertext: %i\n", text[i]+k)
```

which at least returned something:

```
$./caesar 1
Plaintext: a
Cyphertext: 146

$./caesar 5
Plaintext: a
Cyphertext: 150
```

So, basically, it is adding `k` to 150 -which is 'û' in ASCII, so...(?).

**And, finally**, apart from the fact the program returns a number I do not understand, I thought I could make it show up like letters/non-numerical characters adding this:

```
printf("Cyphertext: %i\n", (char)text[i]+k);
```

but it actually does not, the program returns exactly the same last output shown above.

So well, this is a much longer question than I expected, but I hope someone in here has the patence and proficency to answer it.

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: line 15 of your code you declared a variable of type string. String is not a native C type. Are you sure you're coding in C?

Comment: Use the modulus operator, %, to keep the 'encrypted' value in range. "text[i] + k % 26"

Comment: (And of couse use atoi() or strtol() or similar to convert the command line arg to an integer)

Comment: @woz, He's coding in C with the cs50 definitions and library.  I'd call that a specific variation on "coding in C", but YMMV.  Added the [cs50] tag.

Comment: `if(text[i]>='a' && text[i]<='z')` is an assumption about the character set in use, and it's not always true.  The only characters that are represented consecutively per the C Standard are digits.  If you want to know if a character is a lowercase letter, use [the `islower()` function.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/islower.html)

Comment: Thank you all, guys! I am still having some trouble with the program, but this particular problem is solved.
@woz, as far as I understand, I am coding in C. I don't know much, but I am enrolled in this CS50 HarvardX course, which works in an online IDE; and as far as I include all libraries used in the course, I am fine - not sure what belongs in C and what does not, though. basically what [@]JohnBollinger said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line arguments are always passed in as strings.  Just because your program expects the first argument to look like a number doesn't necessarily mean that a number gets passed in.

So when you get the first character in the string via `argv[1][0]`, you're not picking up the value 1 but the **character** `1`.  Assuming ASCII is used for characters, this character has an ASCII value of 49.  So `k` in this case has the value 49.

You need to convert the argument to a number.  You can use the `atoi` function for this:

```
int k = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to convert a digit (`'0'`-`'9'`) to a number, you can simply subtract the Ascii code for `'0'` from your input.

```
char digit;
int num = digit - '0';
```

You should check your input is within the range first.

```
if (digit < '0' || '9' < digit)
    //  error!!
```

Answer (score 2):

The general purpose solution is

```
int k = atoi(argv[1]);
```

atoi takes a string and converts it to a number. The subtract solution above only deals with single digits, this will allow k > 9